# Git central branch development

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently working on a development team which is split up such that individuals or small groups are working on completely independent features, using git as version control. We have a central branch (trunk), which occasionally is updated for refactoring or from merged features.

Either through lack of proper jargon or comprehension, I have been unable to find a method of accomplishing the following: we would like for the central trunk to 'automatically' filter its updates down into the development branches, without having to rebranch after every update. If a feature branch is merged into central, it should become part of all the other current development branches.

This seems to me like the kind of thing that would be a common and easy task. If so, can someone suggest a method of doing it? If it is not common (or possible), please say why is this considered poor practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't do it automatically is that the changes aren't guaranteed to be compatible. If you wish to incorporate changes from master into the feature branches you can use

```
git merge master
```

The only part that could be considered "poor practice" is that in software development you should keep each feature small and self contained. Maybe a better method is to separate each feature into a number of smaller features?

Comment: I tried running this with my own feature branch checked out, and it only says "Already up to date". However none of the changes are reflected and the logs do not say anything about changes to master.

Comment: Do you have a local copy of master/trunk?

Comment: @frog, If your main branch is called `trunk`, try `git fetch` followed by `git merge origin/trunk`.

Comment: Good call, Massey: I had to update my local trunk branch before I could do the merge. Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Make sure you read Makoto's link too. It has a lot of helpful information. This might also be helpful: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely misunderstanding something, or at least you're missing a critical piece when working with Git with a lot of others:  [a **workflow**.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow)

By default, Git doesn't do any automatic merging of any kind whatsoever without the guidance of a human there to be sure that Git has done the right thing.  In order to merge, you have to run the commands manually, and good code hygiene dictates that you would then run your integration/unit tests against that merge to ensure that nothing managed to break.

A lot of this *can* be automated, but Git doesn't do that automation for you out of the box.

The link above gives you some insights into the different types of workflows out there, but bear in mind that there are a lot, and they may not all work for you and your situation.

I will give you some advice when it comes to ensuring that every branch is up to date with master:

- The developer working on that branch is responsible for ensuring that their code is up to date.
- Rebasing your code against master is more preferable than merging master into your topic branch, as you avoid a lot of senseless and pointless merges.
- Do not simply let the tool do all of the things; you have to intervene at a human level every now and then, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Makoto! I may have misled when I said 'automatically'--I meant only that running `git pull` would notice if the trunk had any new updates. In regards to the Atlassian link, that is a fantastic resource, but the length of articles can be intimidating when all the terminology sounds the same to the uninitiated.